# CSS aesthetics help for CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the contacts in my search page symmetrical in their own separate columns within the table. The top row works fine, but rows 2 and 3 have some issues.

My goal: to have the titles all be aligned with each other instead of having them higher or lower than the rest on their respective rows.

Here the content:

http://jsfiddle.net/NwUpv/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply this css

```
td
{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Technically this aligns the content within the `<td>` to the top of the cell.  But since you have identical formatting on your titles, it should have the effect of aligning your titles as well.